# Is there a way to use os.path.exists with a wildcard string?

Tags: python

I have a directory `dir` and inside the directory there may be files with filenames of the form:

```
YYYY-MM-DD-data.db
```

where `YYYY-MM-DD` can be any year, month, day.

Usually I use `os.path.exists` to check for the existence of a path, but in this case I need to check if any of such files exist. I don't think `os.path.exists` is directly compatible with a wildcard match? Can someone advise on how to do this?

My current approach is:

```
filename_pattern = "*-data.db"
matching_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(/path/to/dir, filename_pattern))
assert matching_files
```

Comment: Maybe you could get the list of all files and then apply a regex on it?

Comment: What went wrong with the approach you show?  It should work just fine - the list returned by `glob()` will be non-empty if there were any matches, a non-empty list is truthy when used in a boolean context.

Comment: @jasonharper nothing, I was just hoping for a one liner using `os.path.exists`

Comment: Just do `len(glob.glob(os.path.join(/path/to/dir, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-data.db'))) > 0`

Comment: one liner: `assert glob.glob(os.path.join(/path/to/dir, '*-data.db'))`

Comment: That said, _grumph_ about prioritization of terseness over readability and maintainability. Worry about making code robust and easy to understand, not about making it short.

Comment: (Note that to be on-topic here, questions are [supposed to be practical in nature](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask); if there's no practical "actual problem you face" solved by using `os.path.exists`, it isn't a topical question)

Answer (score 1):

If it was possible, it is not documented: https://peps.python.org/pep-0519/

If you seek for a less convoluted style, you might find pathlib nicer:

```
from pathlib import Path
filename_pattern = "*-data.db"
matching_files = Path(/path/to/dir).rglob(filename_patter)  # or .glob for non-recursive
assert list(matching_files)  # [r]glob(*) returns an generator
```